# Firebase Cloud Functions deploy async function with NPM 8

Tags: firebase, async-await, google-cloud-functions

my functions package.json

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~5.13.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.0",
    "puppeteer": "^1.6.2"
},
"engines": {
    "node": "8"
}
```

my old non async functions get deployed. But not my new async one:

```
exports.screenshot = async  (req, res) => {
  const url = "https://google.de"; // req.query.url;

  if (!url) {
    return res.send('Please provide URL as GET parameter, for example: <a href="?url=https://example.com">?url=https://example.com</a>');
  }

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ["--no-sandbox"]
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);
  const imageBuffer = await page.screenshot();
  await browser.close();

  res.set("Content-Type", "image/png");
  res.send(imageBuffer);
};
```

when running: `firebase deploy --only functions:screenshot`
I get the error:

```
The following functions are found in your project but do not exist in your local source code:
        screenshot(us-central1)
```

what can I do?

Comment: Async/Await has been supported since Node 7.6. Are you linting the script?

Comment: linting gives no erros. Problem is that it is not detected by the deploy script

Comment: Please edit the question to show more specifically what the error is.  Is there output from the command line that describes the problem?

Comment: I get no error. The async function isn't deployed (recognized?)

Comment: are you issuing `Module.exports` anywhere else in your node script? If so, that overrides your individual `export`

Comment: No I don't use Module.exports anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exports.screenshot = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
...
});
```

did it for me